# Silverlight 3 - Find Element inside items control

Tags: silverlight

I have an ItemsControl that is bound to a collection of objects. Each object has it's own collection as well as other vital properties.  To display the objects within an object, I'm displaying a TreeView inside of a ItemsControl. I know this sounds crazy. But, this is just a trimmed down version of what I am trying to accomplish to keep the question focused on the problem. Here is my sample:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <controls:TreeView x:Name="myTreeView">
      </controls:TreeView>
    </DataTemplate>                                     
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                                        
</ItemsControl>
```

When a user clicks a button, I need to retrieve the current TreeView associated with a specific object. In an attempt to do this, I am trying the following:

```
MyClass instanceToFind = (MyClass)(IdentifyDesiredInstance());                
foreach (MyClass instance in myItemsControl.Items)
{
  if (instance.ID == instanceToFind.ID)
  {
     TreeView treeView = null; // How do I get the TreeView?

     // Do other necessary updates  
  }
}
```

The code snippet above shows where I am trying to get the TreeView. How do I get the TreeView when looping through the items in an itemscontrol?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`VisualTreeHelper.GetChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild(VS.95).aspx) and [`VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchildrencount(VS.95).aspx) methods to iterate through the view's children until you find the tree that corresponds to your item. You should be able to check the `TreeView.DataContext` property against your item to verify its the right one. Note, you need to use this recursively as `GetChild` only retrieves immediate children.

As you'd need to iterate the visual tree anyway, I recommend abandoning your current loop and instead, just looping the children, checking the ID of their data contexts.